# save part of matlab cell array, proper refence

Tags: matlab

I found the following piece of MATLAB code previously posted by someone here:

```
x = cell(3,4);
save x;
matObj = matfile('x.mat','writable',true);
matObj.x(3,4) = {eye(10)};
```

It creates a .mat file with a 3x4 cell array in it, and the content of the cell positioned at (3,4) is a 10x10 identity matrix.

What would be the right syntax to read the .mat file and change the value of the element positioned at (2,3) in the identity matrix to say -5?

If it were possible to use the curly braces I would do it as mat.Obj.x{3,4}(2,3)=-5, but MATLAB says this type of referencing for cell arrays is not supported.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, there is no way in matlab to reference `matlab.io.MatFile` objects like you want. The easier way would be just to create a temporary variable to do it.

Thus instead trying to do this:

```
matObj.x(3,4) = {eye(10)};
matObj.x{3,4}(2,3)=-5; % this will lead to error, as you noticed
```

do like this:

```
tmpVar = eye(10);
tmpVar(2,3) = -5;    
matObj.x(3,4) = {tmpVar};
```

Comment: Well, thank you, this is a solution but only so long as the temp variable is not memory demanding. I intentionally wanted to avoid having to load the entire matrix into the memory only to update it and then save back into the mat file. For the matrix is just too big to be loaded into the memory entirely. Any thoughts on how to do it without having to load the whole matrix into the memory?